# How to create a cron job that triggers every 6 minutes between 9 am and 1 am?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am trying to create a cron job that triggers every 6 minutes between the hours of 9 am and 1 am. The code I currently have is below.

```
*/6 9-0 * * *
```

The issue I am having is that this is being triggered every 6 minutes but it only happens between 1 am and 9 am instead of the other way around. Can someone give me a hand on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*/6 09-00 * * *
*/6 00-01 * * *

I've split it in two, should work.